# Are getters and setters the only way to avoid prototype mutations?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object, and I want to extend it. The problem is that it's variables mutate from one scope to another.

First, I create a Mammal prototype, and he has a name, this name can be printed with the `whoAmI` function

```
var Mammal = ( function () {

    var whoAmI = function () {
        console.log("I am " + this.name);
    };

    return {
        name : "mammal",
        whoAmI : whoAmI
    };

})();
```

Then, I create a Dog, who has a name too. It's name can be printed, directly from `whoAmI`, or from the `state` function.

```
var Dog = ( function (mammal) {
    mammal.name = "dog";

    mammal.state = function () {
    mammal.whoAmI();
    console.log("I am happy");
    };

    return mammal;

})(Object.create(Mammal));
```

But when i want to create an instance of Dog, and set his name from the outside, there seem to be two `name` variable: one in Dog, and another in the new created variable `shipo`.

```
var shipo = Object.create(Dog);
shipo.name = "Shipo"
shipo.state(); // it's name is dog
shipo.whoAmI(); // it's name is Shipo
// mutation? :(
```

I can solve this, by implementing a getter and a setter function for the `name` variable, on the Mammal definition... but I hate using getters and setters, my code would be shorter if variables could be publicly setted and getted without this ugly functions...

Are getters and setters the only way to prevent this kind of mutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is very simple is this case: just call `this.whoAmI()` instead of `mammal.whoAmI()` to access current object instead of its prototype property:

```
var Dog = ( function (mammal) {
    mammal.name = "dog";
    mammal.state = function () {
        this.whoAmI();
        console.log("I am happy");
    };
    return mammal;
})(Object.create(Mammal));
```

will give expected result:

> I am Shipo 
>   I am happy 
>   I am Shipo

Here is simplified scheme of the inheritance chain:

```
+--------------+       +--------------+   
| Mammal       |  +--> | Dog          |
+--------------+  |    +--------------+
| __proto__    |--+    | __proto__    |
+--------------+       +--------------+
| name: mammal |       | name: dog    |
| whoAmI()     |       | state()      |
+--------------+       +--------------+
```

From this table it's easy to see that if an instance of `Dog` calls `state` method you want it to be invoked on the current `this` object so it can pick up `this.name`, not `mammal.name`.

Comment: I was afraid this solution wouldn't allow me to extend Dog, because `this.whoAmI`, would cause name to be the Dog's name, so I made this to test it: http://pastebin.com/1RCfhT1H , and it works perfectly! thanks a lot :D